# read line from text file then How show line 1st word textbox1 until : symbol then 2nd textbox show after : symbol?

Tags: c#, textbox, streamreader

My have below process 1 .txt file

```
firstname:lastname
sumon:kamal
abdul:halim
kamrul:khan
rafiq: akbor
```

How I am show 1st name textbox1 with 2nd textbox show last name?

Example for clear

textbox1 show sumon & textbox2 show kamal

I am trying more road but still not getting any road for this.

I am trying using streamReader for show textbox data but full line only coming.

How reading 1 line with 2 textbox both name?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

If I take your question right, you want something like this.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    private const string PATH = "C:\\person.txt";

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // read lines from file at specified path
        var lines = File.ReadLines(PATH);

        // take first line from aquired collection
        var line = lines.FirstOrDefault();
        if (line == null)
            return;

        // split string to first and last names
        var parts = line.Split(':');
        if (parts.Length != 2)
            return;

        // send them to textBox.Text property
        textBox1.Text = parts[0];
        textBox2.Text = parts[1];
    }
}
```

Don't forget drop textBox1 and textBox2 to your form.
Iterate over lines if you need something else.

Comment: {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var lines = File.ReadLines("D:\\ovi");
       // take first line from aquired collection
        var line = lines.FirstOrDefault();
        if (line == null)
            return;
        var parts = line.Split(':');
        if (parts.Length != 2)
            return;
        textBox1.Text = parts[0];
        textBox2.Text = parts[1];
    }
}
        }

Comment: I am using windows form application with don't know how using class so I am new person in there so can you give me how directly puting this in c# windows application? I am using webbrowser windows application form. Please give me something good clear. I am need this urgently with It's really important for me. Mabe your help I am going success.

Comment: Excellent working!!! Great Support from StackOverflow. I am really happy to collected site from google. Really Excellent your support Really. Many Thanks Got must help in your life.